# syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, array-push

how can i rid of this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

PHP code:

```
$uniqueOrderCodes = array();
foreach ($checks as $check)
{
    array_push($uniqueOrderCodes,"string" => $check);
}
```

thanx alot

Comment: Don't use `array_push()`. just set the key:  `$uniqueOrderCodes['string'] = $check;`

Comment: Can you look at related questions, search in Google or anything? It's parse error...

Comment: But since this is in a loop, you're overwriting `string` on every iteration! Please let us know what you _are trying to acheive_.

Comment: i want to achive this
 "uniqueOrderCodes" => array("string" => "66/2121-1003-36614","string" => "66/2121-1003-36614")

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian That is not valid. You cannot use the same key `string` multiple times in the array. Do you mean that you want it to be a string type? To get what you want, you just need to append to the array and it will be numerically indexed. `$uniqueOrderCodes[] = $check;`

Comment: the webservice accept that

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian PHP cannot produce an array like that. It will overwrite the `string` key.  What web service is this?

Comment: it didnt worked see this : [link](http://websvc.highsell.ir/cart.asmx?op=ChangeBatchOrderStatus)

Comment: didn't you understand any thing?

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian You cannot construct that XML from a PHP array. If you are using SoapClient or something, post more of your code. There are many ways to build XML with PHP.

Comment: this works

$ChangeBatchOrderStatusResult=$proxy->ChangeBatchOrderStatus (array("authenticationID" => $signIn['SignInResult'],
                     "uniqueOrderCodes" => $array("string" => "66/2121-1003-11111","string" => "66/2121-1003-22222"),
                     "newStatuses" => array("int" => "2","int" => "2")));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No offense intended, but you should read [the manual](http://php.net/array_push). `=>` it is an assignment operator and is used in arrays.

In the example `$my_array = array('color' => 'blue')`,  `color` is the key, `blue` is the value (*of type `string`*) and `$my_array` is the variable holding the array. In a *nerdy* language, that could sound like *"Variable `$my_array` is holding an array in which I assigned a string `blue` to key `color` ; I can access that by using `$my_array['color']` which will output `blue`."*

You push to arrays like this:

```
array_push($my_array, $var);
```

`$var` it can be of a `mixed` (*mixed = any*) type like `string`, `int`, `array`, etc.

However, for just one element, you do not need to `push` in array. Alternative:

```
foreach ($checks as $check)
{
    $uniqueOrderCodes[] = $check;
}
```

See:

- [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)
- [array_push()](http://php.net/array_push)